# Convergence Error with Lifelines CoxPHFitter when using sklearn adapter, but no error when using CoxPHfitter directly

Tags: python, survival, cox-model

I want to evaluate my Cox model using cross validation for which lifelines package does not support. So I must use the sklearn adapter. However, when I fit my cox model using the sklearn adapter, I get a convergence error. Inexplicably, I do not get a convergence error when I fit my cox model on the exact same data with the exact same parameters using the CoxPHfitter directly.

```
X = test_data.drop('DxToFollowup', axis=1) 
Y = test_data['DxToFollowup']
CoxRegression = sklearn_adapter(CoxPHFitter, event_col='IsDead')
sk_cph = CoxRegression(penalizer=.1)

scores = cross_val_score(sk_cph, X, Y, cv=3)
```

Give me the error

```
ConvergenceError: Convergence halted due to matrix inversion problems. 
Suspicion is high `collinearity. Please see the following tips in the lifelines documentation: 
https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#problems-with-convergence-in-the-cox-proportional-hazard-modelMatrix is singular.
```

However when I run

```
cph = CoxPHFitter(penalizer=0.1)
cph.fit(test_data, duration_col='DxToFollowup', event_col='IsDead', show_progress=True)
cph.print_summary()
```

It converges with no issues. I have even tried reducing the penalty to 0.000001 but this does not help.

Comment: Likely the reason is the `cv=3` - it's splitting the original dataset into smaller datasets, and it's possible that training on these smaller datasets produce a singularity. How large is your dataset?

Comment: 119 observations 104 events.

Comment: Try a _higher_ cv. How many columns are there?

Comment: That's interesting. Choosing cv=5 seems to work. There are 23 columns. I have 6 continuous variables and 5 categorical variables. I found that one variable in particular was causing the issue. I am not sure why 5 works, but with cv=5 I can keep all the variables

Comment: Are you dropping one of the categories in each categorical variable? Another problem could be i) a rare category that isn't present in the training df (i.e. all 0s),  or ii) because there are 17 categorical variables, and 78 rows (in cv=3), it's possible that two of the encoded variables become co-linear.